# Rust: How to combine the Entry API with owned data?

Tags: rust, hashmap, ownership

I have a `HashMap` and would like to update a value if it exists and otherwise add a default one. Normally I would do it like this:

```
some_map.entry(some_key)
    .and_modify(|e| modify(e))
    .or_insert(default)
```

But now my `modify` has type `fn(T)->T`, but the borrow checker obviously won’t allow me to write:

```
some_map.entry(some_key)
    .and_modify(|e| *e = modify(*e))
    .or_insert(default)
```

What is the preferred way of doing this in Rust? Should I just use `remove` and `insert`?

Comment: I think in such a context like `HashMap.entry(some_key).and_modify(f)`, you should consider providing `f` with type`fn(&mut T)` firstly. `fn(T)->T` is just not a proper choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can create an empty version of your `T` for cheap, you could use `mem::replace`:

```rust
some_map.entry(some_key)
    .and_modify(|e| {
        // swaps the second parameter in and returns the value which was there
        let mut v = mem::replace(e, T::empty());
        v = modify(v);
        // puts the value back in and discards the empty one
        mem::replace(e, v);
    })
    .or_insert(default)
```

this assumes `modify` does not panic though, otherwise you'll find yourself with the "empty" value staying in your map. But you'd have a similar issue with `remove` / `insert`.

Comment: If the empty `T` is not easy but you control the map, switching to a `HashMap<K, Option<T>>` can do the trick.

Comment: There is also this [`replace_with`](https://crates.io/crates/replace_with) crate, if you can take trade-off.